# How do i remove chars from a string?

Tags: c#

I want to remvoe the chars: '"' and ','
I did:

```
string g = mapData.Substring(start, index - start);
g.Replace(@",", "");
g.Replace(@"\", "");
map.Images.Add(g);
```

But in the end when i watch map i see the chars yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings in .NET are immutable. You should re-assign your variable like this:

```
string g = mapData.Substring(start, index - start);
g = g.Replace(@",", "");
g = g.Replace(@"\", "");
map.Images.Add(g);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the fix:

```
string g = mapData.Substring(start, index - start);
map.Images.Add(g.Replace(@",", "").Replace(@"\", ""));
```

Replace returns the string result